# How to ask for permission in my android app within playstore before downloading my app(Like ES File Explorer File Manager)?

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to add the permissions to access the files and location of user in my android app. Right now when the user open my app, it asks for permissions but if the user deny it my app doesn't work fine due to the downloaded images in his phone. It gives bad impact. Now i want to ask that how i can ask for permission in my app within playstore before downloading my app(Like ES File Explorer File Manager). If the user deny this he can't able to install my app.

Comment: Where did you declared your permission ? are you checking for permission on activity page?

Comment: you should read about permission at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html, especially runtime permission https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Bhunnu Baba Yes I am currently checking the permission on activity if the permission is disabled then app will ask for permission.

Comment: @HendraWD my runtime permission is working perfectly fine i have already followed these documents for runtime permission. Now i just need to ask for permission before downloading app from playstore.

Comment: That permission is handled by the device/play store directly, there is nothing you can do

Comment: @Shehroz Abid , when we declare our permissions in our manifest file then, when user install app from the play store a pop-up automatically generate for asking the permissions.

Comment: @Bhunnu Baba , Thanks for showing your interest in my question. You are absolutely right but this will happen when app's target SDK is 22 or lower. i was using app's target SDK 24 so i was facing this issue. Now my issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.

So, i think you can set your target SDK and target API below 22 for using old permission system.

Comment: It is nice to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by selecting API22 as target SDK

> If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.

**BUT ALSO**

> Note: Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level. You should test your app to verify that it behaves properly when it's missing a needed permission, regardless of what API level your app targets.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i will also keep your point while implementing this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some usage permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.
Something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
//for file access
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
//for location access and updates
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
</manifest>
```

after adding these permissions you have to create a new release build and post to play store.
Note: these permissions are working fine for API level below 23 but for API 23 or higher you have to check run-time permissions(marshmallow and nougat), for more info about Requesting Permissions at Run Time please go through this link-https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html